# How do I duplicate 'input required' functionality without sending with the form?

Tags: html, forms, input, required

I would like to have the built-in functionality of having a text `input` (in the middle of other text `input`s) be checked and flagged (i.e. the default red marquee applied around the text box) to make sure it is populated before the user clicks the `form` `submit` button, without including that value in the form submission.  Basically, I don't want to send the retyped password with the form, but it of course needs to be filled in (and will be checked client-side).  Is there a "simple" way to do this?

Comment: @sircapsalot can you be any more specific?

Comment: If it's in the form, it's going to be sent when the user hits submit. There's no way to override that AFAIK. Your options are moving it outside the form (which may not be possible depending on how you set up the HTML) or just ignoring it on the server side.

Comment: Not tested it, but you could try changing the form's action to a hash location so it doesn't go anywhere, then if it's successful change it back to what it should be and programmatically resubmit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very minimal example of what you want.

You can do this type of logic using JavaScript events like `onblur`, `onfocus`, `onchange`, etc.

Here is an example showing you how you can validate that a field has a value in it.

```js
var validate = function(element) {
    // element is HTMLInputElement
    if (element.value == "") {
        element.className = "border-red";
    } else {
        element.className = "";
    }
}
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}

.border-red {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
    Required: <input type="text" name="required_field" onblur="validate(this)" />
    Optional: <input type="text" name="optional" />
</form>
```